# Form with polymorphic images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problems with adding pictures for comments. Comments have a link `has_many` to the pictures `as: :imageable`. How I can add a pictures upload to a comment form?

```
# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :images, as: :imageable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, allow_destroy: true

end

# app/models/Image.rb
class Image < ApplicationRecord
    has_attached_file :img
    validates_attachment :img, content_type: { content_type: 
    ["image/jpg", 
    "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }

    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true, required: false
end

# app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
        @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        @comment.save
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
        @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end

    private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
      end
end

# app/views/comments/_form.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], 
    local:true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

# app/views/articles/show.html.erb
<%= render 'comments/form'%>
```

I managed to add images in comments through ActiveAdmin, but I dont know how to do it with form.
So, what should I add to the form for images? Should I write a method `create` in images_controller?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, youre asking how to nest a child form inside your `Comment` form. This is typically achieved with the [#fields_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for) helper.

For a one-to-many relationship, you can simply do something like the following:

```
<%= form_for(...) ... do |comment_form| %>
  # beginning of form for Comment ...

  <p class="imageables">
    <ul>
    <%= form.fields_for :imageables do |comment_image_form| %>
      <li>
        # Add Image fields here
      </li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </p>

  # rest of form /  submit button
<% end %>
```

Adapt the above to your application's current form. This is only achievable through the [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for) call you've made in `Comment`.

You will also need to look into whitelisting the parameters for the `Image` associations via the [strong parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) pattern. That is, the `#comment_params` method of your `CommentsController` will need the `Image` attributes added, or they will be disregarded with a warning.

I also recommend you load the `fields_for` fields from a partial view, like this:

`<%= render 'comment_image_fields', parent_form: comment_form %>`

Check out the guides for [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms) for more detailed info.

Comment: I added in form `<%= form.fields_for :imageable do |image_form| %>
    <li><%= image_form.label :img %></li>
    <li><%= image_form.file_field :img %></li>
    <% end %>`, in HTML it look like `<input type="file" name="comment[imageable][img]" id="comment_imageable_img">`, but pictures are not load.  `In comment_params` - `imageable_attributes:[:img]` What should be in `comments_controller` and in `Images_controller`?

Comment: @Blueberry_Cat its possible you could be encountering a second issue altogether - I would first verify that you are indeed uploading a file to local (or cloud) storage. Also, you may not have the structure of the strong params hash for your `Comment` correct, or, you may be missing other important attributes for the `Image`. Refer to the Rails guide, and keep experimenting!

Answer (score 0):

User [PaperClip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) Gem.

in your view add :

```
  <%= file_field_tag "imageables[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>
```

in your create method inside controller:

```
 if params[:imageables]
    params[:imageables].each { |image|
      @comment.imagables.create(image: image)
    }
  end
```

Another way which is better: 
Use PaperClip & [Cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for nested forms.